# How to make table td full width in mobile?

Tags: html, mobile, html-table

I am working on html table structure and having one problem in mobile. Following is my table code.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><span style="color: #000000;">Title </span></th>
<th><span style="color: #000000;">Link</span></th>
<th><span style="color: #000000;">Link</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="color: #000000;">Intro</span></td>
<td>Link Here</td>
<td>Link</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="color: #000000;">Intro</span></td>
<td>Link Here</td>
<td>Link</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="color: #000000;">Intro</span></td>
<td>Link Here</td>
<td>Link</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make td full width in mobile.

Comment: im going to assume you know that this already is full width right?

Comment: @Jack Have you used <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the head section?

Comment: @Scott Chambers  Intro, Link Here and Link is showing in same row. But i wanna intro in first row , Link Here  in second and Link in third.

Comment: im confused? @jack then you've made the table wrong. then everything between a tr = table row. so if you want one line in same row. You'd need to add it in the <tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `media Query` this way & `HTML` with `data-th`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  table#customDataTable caption {
    background-image: none;
  }
  table#customDataTable thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody td {
    display: block;
    padding: .6rem;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody tr td:first-child {
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody tr td:first-child a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody tr td:first-child:before {
    color: rgb(225, 181, 71);
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody td:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10rem;
  }
  table#customDataTable tr th:last-child,
  table#customDataTable tr td:last-child {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" id="customDataTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><span style="color: #000000;">Title </span></th>
<th><span style="color: #000000;">Link</span></th>
<th><span style="color: #000000;">Link</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-th="Title"><span style="color: #000000;">Intro</span></td>
<td data-th="Link">Link Here</td>
<td data-th="Link">Link</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-th="Title"><span style="color: #000000;">Intro</span></td>
<td data-th="Link">Link Here</td>
<td data-th="Link">Link</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-th="Title"><span style="color: #000000;">Intro</span></td>
<td data-th="Link">Link Here</td>
<td data-th="Link">Link</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help. Thats what i was looking for.